# Unexpected traversal of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having trouble figuring out why my linked list is not "visiting nodes" properly. It seems my code is one step behind where I want it to be. The visited nodes only begin to stack after the third node is added, when it should be stacking after the second node is added. It makes sense to me that this logic should work since when the first node is created and the second is initialized to NULL, the while doesn't hit and nothing is printed. Then second node is created and added to the end of the list and the third node is now NULL. When we loop on this iteration it should be printing the first node since temp->next is not NULL at the first node.

Not sure what I'm not seeing here. Where is my logic wrong?

```
void addToList(waitList** head, char *name, int numBurgers, int numSalads)
{
    waitList *new = (waitList*) malloc (sizeof(waitList));
    new->name = name;
    new->numBurgers = numBurgers;
    new-> numSalads = numSalads;

    new-> next = NULL;

    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = new;
    }
    else
    {
        waitList *temp = *head;

        while(temp->next != NULL )
        {
            
            
            printf("Visiting node %s with values %d and %d\n", temp->name, temp->numBurgers, temp->numSalads);
            
            temp = temp-> next;
        }

        temp->next = new;
    }
}
```

Output I'm getting:

```
Enter command: a 3 3 nick
Adding In-restaurant order for "nick": 3 burgers and 3 salads

Enter command: a 4 4 bob
Adding In-restaurant order for "bob": 4 burgers and 4 salads

Enter command: a 6 6 kevin
Adding In-restaurant order for "kevin": 6 burgers and 6 salads
Visiting node nick with values 3 and 3

Enter command: a 9 9 max
Adding In-restaurant order for "max": 9 burgers and 9 salads
Visiting node nick with values 3 and 3
Visiting node bob with values 4 and 4
```

Expected output:

```
Enter command: a 3 3 nick
Adding In-restaurant order for "nick": 3 burgers and 3 salads

Enter command: a 4 4 bob
Adding In-restaurant order for "bob": 4 burgers and 4 salads
Visiting node nick with values 3 and 3

Enter command: a 6 6 kevin
Adding In-restaurant order for "kevin": 6 burgers and 6 salads
Visiting node nick with values 3 and 3
Visiting node bob with values 4 and 4

Enter command: a 9 9 max
Adding In-restaurant order for "max": 9 burgers and 9 salads
Visiting node nick with values 3 and 3
Visiting node bob with values 4 and 4
Visiting node kevin with values 6 and 6
```

Comment: Although `new` is not a C keyword, it *is* a C++ keyword.  Inasmuch as translating code from C to C++ is a thing that is sometimes done, I would recommend avoiding use of `new` as an identifier C.  Besides, I would also recommend choosing a more specific identifier anyway, such as `newList`.

Answer (score 1):

```c
        waitList *temp = *head;

        while(temp->next != NULL )
        {
            
            
            printf("Visiting node %s with values %d and %d\n", temp->name, temp->numBurgers, temp->numSalads);
            
            temp = temp-> next;
        }
```

You take the first element in your list (*head) then check if its `next` is null.

After adding the first element to the list, you have one element (the head) and the second element has not been added yet.

```c
        waitList *temp = *head;

        while(1)
        {            
            printf("Visiting node %s with values %d and %d\n", temp->name, temp->numBurgers, temp->numSalads);
            
            if (temp->next == NULL) {
                break;
            }
            temp = temp-> next;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where is my logic wrong?

Your logic for adding nodes is fine.  Your logic for printing existing nodes when adding a new one omits the last node in the list, because it only prints nodes that satisfy the `while` condition, `temp->next != NULL`.

There are numerous ways to fix it.  Here's one I like:

```
waitList dummy = { .next = *head };
waitList *last = &dummy;

for (waitList *temp = last->next; temp; last = temp, temp = last->next) {
    printf("Visiting node %s with values %d and %d\n", temp->name,
            temp->numBurgers, temp->numSalads);
}

last->next = new;
```

With that, the `temp` pointer runs one node ahead of the current `last` pointer as you traverse the list, with `last` starting out pointing to a dummy node preceding the real head.  That way you avoid advancing `last` past the true last node, and `temp` takes values pointing to each existing node in turn, including the last one.

Note also that if you add ...

```
*head = dummy.next;
```

... then you no longer need a special case for the first node.